# Which word to use between two streets when describing an intersection, and or at?

Tags: grammar, dialects

I would normally write an intersection like:

A St. and B St.

but I've noticed many people also write

A St. at B St.

I've tried googling every way I can think of phrasing this and I can't find anything.

Which is correct? If both are correct, then what determines which form someone usually uses(e.g. country, age, etc)?

Comment: Would you mind posting a full sentence with the "at" usage? It might help clarify how the author is using the term. Please use the [edit] link to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Referring to a location at *A St. at B St.* indicates that A St. is the primary axis of travel, with B St. being a point of reference along that axis. This is particularly the case if the address is not exactly at *the intersection of* or *the corner of* A and B, but a little bit beyond.

I thought it might be useful to illustrate some expressions with an example map from a town near me. The primary routes are east-west (Cameron Street and King Street as shown here).

[image: '']

1. This building can be described as being located *at [the corner of] Cameron Street and North Fairfax Street* (or the reverse). It has equal frontage on both streets, and one can access it from either direction. But because you are most likely traveling along Cameron Street to get there, it would not be incorrect to say it is *on Cameron Street at North Fairfax Street*.
2. This building is located *on North Royal Street between Cameron Street and King Street*, although closer to the former, so if you are traveling northbound on North Royal, you might describe it as *on North Royal Street before Cameron Street*, and if traveling southbound, *on North Royal Street past Cameron Street*.
3. This building is situated on the corner but aligned along Cameron Street; I would describe as being *on Cameron Street at North Lee Street* or *on Cameron Street at the corner with North Lee Street*.
4. This market area and fountain is very large, covering the full city block. I might describe it as *along King Street between North Royal and North Fairfax Streets*, but could equally well say it is located at either intersection, or on either side street at King Street.

Answer (score 3):

If something is on A Street at B Street, it's located on A Street near the intersection of A Street and B Street.

"A Street and B Street" is the intersection itself. If we say something is at A Street and B Street, we haven't said which of those streets it's on.